# How to use a dynamic scope name in an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to create a directive that allows me to set a scope variable as a variable name that is passed through as a data attribute.

I currently have the following:

```
<input create-user-dropdown ng-model="userValue" data-my-var="myVar" />

app.directive('createUserDropdown', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           myVarNameHere: "="
        }
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
                $scope.myVarNameHere = value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

How can I use the variable name that is passed through `data-my-var` as the scope variable instead of the current one in my directive that is currently named `myVarNameHere`?

Comment: use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), like `$scope[myVarNameHere]`

Comment: @Grundy - And how do I do the same thing inside `scope: { myVarNameHere: "=" }`?

Comment: seems like you not need isolated scope, use variable directly from scope. also can you explain with sample what you want? now it not clear

Comment: Just so you can understand what I am trying to do - I am trying to add a directive to many inputs that I have on the same page. The directive will capture when an input has changed and will then use the name value to call an API to check the database for any matches. The directive needs to return the API results, and I then need to render the results as a dropdown under the input.

Comment: when you say `myVarNameHere` what you expected? `myVar`? or value for myVar?

Comment: That's correct. When I say `myVarNameHere`, I expect whatever scope variable name is passed through `data-my-var`, so in this case the scope variable name is `myVar`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83535/discussion-between-grundy-and-fizzix).

Comment: Look for the example from the [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as we found out in the comments you can create directive with template like

```
.directive('myDir', function($http) {
  return {
    scope:{
      val: '=',//variable from parent scope for handling input value, if result of input not used outside directive can be removed
      template: '=' // template url for repeated div
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="val" ng-change="search()" />'+
              '<div ng-repeat="item in founded" ng-include="template"></div>',
    link: function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
      scope.search = function(){// create change handler
        //use value `data-service` attribute as service name
        $http.get(iAttrs.service).success(function(data){
          scope.founded = data;
        });
      }    
    }

  }
}
```

working **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qseB7BYEea1pKCz8lPa?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<input create-user-dropdown ng-model="userValue" data-my-var="myVar" />

app.directive('createUserDropdown', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           myVarNameHere: "=myVar"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
                scope.myVarNameHere = value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The `data-my-var` value is dynamic and will be different for every input I have. So how can I set the `myVarNameHere: "=myVar"` as the value that is passed through the data attribute?

Comment: after `=` sign - not value attribute, but attribute name, so in case in sample `myVarNameHere` is linked to value for attribute `data-my-var`

Comment: data-my-var has a value of myVar - it's not treated as a value. So you need to define a $scope.myVar param in your controller